# Duplicate a list and associated custom workflows

Tags: 2007, list, sharepoint-designer, custom-form, designer-workflow

I have a list with custom forms (created in Designer) and custom workflows (also created in Designer). It has been decided that that information entered into this list should be kept in two lists in future. Is there an easy way to duplicate the columns, custom forms and custom workflows?

- I can't save the list as a template, I get an acess denied message when I 
  click the link. I can try contacting those above me but I imagine they have removed access for a reason!
- I don't have access to central administration (not sure if this would help on this occassion)

I'm sure the answer is no but I thought I'd ask before I manually go through and take the time creating everything again. If the answer is no then please let me know so I'm not left hanging!

Comment: Saving list is template is only option seems to be possible! Wait for other experts to answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had an administrator with mnore powers than me save the list as a template so that's helped with the actual list, now I just need to get the workflows copied...